# Python: Template for printing out select values

Tags: python, function

So, I know the title seems odd, but so is the question:
I've been taking a break from Javascript to mess around with some python some more, and I was wondering if there was a way to create a "Template" so I don't have to keep typing the wwname, wworigin, and wwidn over and over in the functions
thanks 
[code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7rL3.png)

Comment: please post your code inside the post

Comment: `class` is probably what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for [string formating](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

In your code you could define a function and call it inside your `print()`:

```
def tpl_print(name, origin, idn):
    return "\nname: {0}\norigin: {1}\nidn: {2}".format(name, origin, idn)

print(tpl_print("horse", "Europe", "001"))
```

Will print:

```
name: horse
origin: Europe
idn: 001
```